# Automatic emphasis of certain words?

Tags: org-mode

When working in `org-mode`, I usually emphasize some key words.  For example, I usually write *Python*, and when I do, I want `org-mode` to use boldface automatically:

```
python => *python*
```

How do I set it up to make these changes automatic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to look at [`abbrev-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode).  Here's a [tutorial](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_abbrev_mode.html).

Basically, with `abbrev-mode`, you follow this procedure:

1. Turn on `abbrev-mode`
2. When you type a word the way you want it to appear, you then [define an abbreviation](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs_manual/emacs/Defining-Abbrevs.html) for whatever you want emacs to recognize and auto-expand
3. type away